# Javascript popup box with string variable to set height and width

Tags: javascript, html

Create a button called “GO TO OTHER WEBSITES” on your form that will call a function to give a popup window to go to the user’s choice of url and window size. 
The function will use a prompt box to give the user at least 3 choices of urls (other websites related to your website) to choose from. 
Use a switch statement to set the chosen url and validate the user choice, do not continue until you have a valid choice. 
The user will then be prompted to enter the height and width of the window in pixels. This must be validated for a minimum height and width of 300. 
Display the chosen url in a window using this resolution. (Hint: to set the additional properties of the window.open method you will need to create a string variable to set the width and height.)

Not too hard I thought, 
I can do a switch statement okay and this is my code and I can have a set window size, setting it up to have a prompt for the user to set width and height and a min value is proving quite difficult

---

here is my java script

```
function myPopup2(){ 
  var url = Number (prompt("Which website do you choose? 1. Google 2. Yahoo 3. Moodle", "")); 
  switch (url) { 
    case 1: 
      window.open(url="http://www.google.com/", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0"); 

      break; 
    case 2: 
      window.open(url="https://au.yahoo.com/", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0"); 

      break; 
    case 3: 
      window.open(url ="http://learn.tafesa.edu.au/","myWindow","status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0"); 

      break; 
    default: 
      alert("Please enter number 1, 2, or 3 to select a website"); 
      break; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works for you. It repeats the prompt until the value you entered is a number and greater than 300.

```js
var height;
while(!isFinite(height) || height < 300) {
    height = prompt("Enter a height > 300");
}
//do the same with width
```